# Alternative to play audio during call in android

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I am implementing automatic call response application in android.In my application the call is respond by the audio file which is recorded by user and that file will play when incoming call is answered automatically by program.I have searched for it to know how to do this but all are saying that this is not possible in android to play audio file during call.So, I want to know what are the alternatives that can be used for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to android official docs, it is not possible to play audio while a call.

See the docs here :[`https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#basics)

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

As an alternative you can use Twilio : https://www.ipragmatech.com/play-audio-file-android-call-using-twilio/

Comment: For the twilio how many numbers i need to serve each incoming call? because they are playing audio from the sever side which is later transfer to the phone